# Is there still a need to use a css preprocessor when implementing css-modules

Tags: css, less, css-modules

I know the 'compose' feature from css-modules helps to do partially at least what variables/mixin do.
What css-module can't do is mixin where we pass a parameter.

```
 /*less using param*/
 .flexJustify(@value){
   display: flex;
   justify-content:@value;
 }
 /*call of the mixin*/
 .box{
  .flexJustify(space-between);
 }
```

Is there any other use cases where implementing a preprocessor with css-module can be useful?

Comment: css-modules is only for scoping portions of your css. Preprocessing is only for writing your css more easily.